# Users not accepting answer and not upvoting

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer

I think this question may already be in place but i just want to give a suggestion. The issue here is that some users *don't accept* the answer even when they say that their problem is solved and also they *don't upvote*. I just wanted to say that there should be some statement at end of every answer saying:

> If this post is helpful please upvote and if your problem is solved please accept as answer

Like I have seen on *socail.msdn* there is a statement at end of every answer:

> If a post answers your question, please click "Mark As Answer" on that post and "Mark as Helpful".

So I think here we should have some statement like this.

Comment: We don't want to badger people into it. If you get votes, you get votes... and just be glad they're leaving instead of downvoting, which you seem to ignore. Not all answers are good, nor are all answers bad but there's no reason to bash every user's head in with a constant reminder. Remember, there are only so many votes per day per user. :)

Comment: `backticks` are ***FOR CODE FORMATTING***, not `to` mark `random` words!

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think I'm going to make that one of my auto comments, including an attribution to you.

Comment: @Catija haha, I'm honored :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the end of the day, there is no way to force the questioner to accept an answer - reminders may help those who are not used to how Stack Exchange works.  But there is no way to force anyone to vote up (or down, for the matter).

Some people, like me, will wait for a while to see if any other answers turn up as well.

Some people simply choose not to accept an answer.

As mentioned in the comments, pestering people to accept is likely to result in them ***not*** accepting the answer.

If users don't have sufficient rep, then they can not upvote (may have less than the required 15 rep) and once they earn it, they may have forgotten to come back. Maybe they have used up their vote quota in the day.

Maybe the answer was not *that* helpful and they are being very polite.

Acceptance and upvotes can not be forced as much as commenting for downvotes cannot **and should not** be forced.

One main point though, if the acceptance (and rep) are what you are after, then you are here for the wrong reasons - their thanks is validation enough that you helped them.

Comment: I would like to add that if you're answering a question of a new user and that user leaves a comment to thank you, I point out how we say *thanks/that helped me* and try to remove that comment when any answer got accepted.